# Reverse elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I setup an  array and i would like to create a method that will  return an array with the elements in reverse. e.g.  if there are 10 slots then `array1[9] = 6` so then `array2[0] = 6`.
I suppose i have to return an array - how would i do that? 
And i dont know how to reverse and add to another array.
Thank you!

```
        int[] arr = {43, 22, 1, 44, 90, 38, 55, 32, 31, 9};
        Console.WriteLine("Before");
        PrintArray(arr);
        Console.WriteLine("After");
        Reverse(arr);

         Console.ReadKey(true);

    }

    static int[] Reverse(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = array.Length; i < 1; i--)
        {
            int x = 0;

            array[i] = array[x++];
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }

       }


         static void PrintArray(int[] array)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[j] + " ");

        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
```

Comment: Can you not just use the ` array.Reverse();` ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Array.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx)

Example from above line

```
public static void Main()  {

  // Creates and initializes a new Array.
  Array myArray=Array.CreateInstance( typeof(String), 9 );
  myArray.SetValue( "The", 0 );
  myArray.SetValue( "quick", 1 );
  myArray.SetValue( "brown", 2 );
  myArray.SetValue( "fox", 3 );
  myArray.SetValue( "jumps", 4 );
  myArray.SetValue( "over", 5 );
  myArray.SetValue( "the", 6 );
  myArray.SetValue( "lazy", 7 );
  myArray.SetValue( "dog", 8 );

  // Displays the values of the Array.
  Console.WriteLine( "The Array initially contains the following values:" );
  PrintIndexAndValues( myArray );

  // Reverses the sort of the values of the Array.
  Array.Reverse( myArray );

  // Displays the values of the Array.
  Console.WriteLine( "After reversing:" );
  PrintIndexAndValues( myArray );
}


public static void PrintIndexAndValues( Array myArray )  {
  for ( int i = myArray.GetLowerBound(0); i <= myArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++ )
     Console.WriteLine( "\t[{0}]:\t{1}", i, myArray.GetValue( i ) );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use the extension method `Reverse`

```
int[] arr = { 43, 22, 1, 44, 90, 38, 55, 32, 31, 9 };
Console.WriteLine("Before");
PrintArray(arr);
Console.WriteLine("After");
PrintArray(arr.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Or if you don't mind modifing the original sequence you can use `Array.Reverse`

```
int[] arr = { 43, 22, 1, 44, 90, 38, 55, 32, 31, 9 };
Console.WriteLine("Before");
PrintArray(arr);
Array.Reverse(arr);
Console.WriteLine("After");
PrintArray(arr);
```

Comment: You have a mess: in fact - `arr.Reverse()` does not change the original, while `Array.Reverse(arr)` - changes!

Comment: Thats EXACTY what I stated. "if you don't mind modifying the original sequence you can use Array.Reverse"

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone who wants to use the Reverse in the first example: you need "using System.Linq".

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse an array by swapping elements from both ends of the array till you reach the middle.

```
for(int start = 0, end = arr.Length - 1; start < arr.Length/2; start++, end--)
{
     swap(arr[start], arr[end]);
}
```

Comment: `arr.length` -> `arr.Length`

Comment: yes thanks! I wrote it considering Java and now I realized OP tagged C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
       int a;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the array length");
        a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter the array element");
        int[] sau = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            sau[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int i =a.Length-1 ; i < 0;i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sau[i]);
        }
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array that has the same length as the old array and reverse is done like this

```
index -> new index  
  0   -> length - 1  
  1   -> length - 1 - 1  
  2   -> length - 1 - 2  
..  
  i   -> length - 1 - i
```

so this translates to this code

```
int[] myVariable = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] reversedVariable =  new int[myVariable.Length]();
for (int i = 0; i < myVariable.Length ; i++)
{
    reversedVariable[myVariable.Length - 1 - i] = myVariable[i];
}
return reversedVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T[] arr;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return arr.Length; }
    }            
public void Reverse()
    {
        T[] newArr = arr;
        arr = new T[Count];
        int number = Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = newArr[number];
            number--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code is doing.

Comment: in Reverse() method you can find one of ways to reverse elements in an array. This is part of cod, with it you can create collection of any type and reverse the collection elements