# C# Transcribing data to the second table and reversing them

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I am will be grateful for help because I am not sure how make this program.
I should code program with two tables. The first will fill it with numbers `Random tab = new Random();`. After that I should reverse numbers and fill them into second table.

I made first functionality but I am not sure how make start with second table?

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] tablica1 = new int[20];

        Random tab = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            tablica1[i] = tab.Next(20);
            Console.WriteLine("Tablica wylosowała nastepujace elementy:");
            Console.WriteLine(tablica1[i]);
        }

        Console.Read();

        int[] tablica2 = new int[20];

        /*for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
        {

        }
       */
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394882/reverse-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: Well, the answers there suggest using an inbuilt method, but this looks more like a homework assignment where they are supposed to do figure out how to do this "manually".

Comment: @KlaudynaZ: 
Do you need to do it without creating another array? If so, I'm guessing you are confused about how to do it without overwriting (and thus, loosing) array elements. Hint: Consider swapping two elements on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't quite describe what exactly happens when you run the code, but I think the problem is with this part - as this should give you an `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
for (int j = tablica2.Length; j > 1 ; j--)
{
    tablica2[j] = tablica1[20-j];
    Console.WriteLine(tablica2[j]);
}
```

The array indices go form `0` to `tablica2.Length - 1` (one less then the length, so the index `tablica2.Length` is *outside* the array).
Your loop goes in reverse from `tablica2.Length` two `2` for some reason.

So as soon as it starts executing, `j` is `20`, but the highest index is `19`.

Change the loop so it goes the full range, and change the loop body so that you don't access out-of-range indices, in one of two ways:

```
for (int j = tablica2.Length - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)   // goes from 19 to 0
{
    tablica2[j] = tablica1[tablica1.Length - j - 1];
}
```

or

```
for (int j = tablica2.Length; j > 0 ; j--)   // goes from 20 to 1
{
    tablica2[j - 1] = tablica1[tablica1.Length - j];
}
```

Comment: Thank You for help! It's working! Now, I understand my mistake! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] tablica1 = new int[20];

    Random tab = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tablica1[i] = tab.Next(20);
        Console.WriteLine("Tablica wylosowała nastepujace elementy:");
        Console.WriteLine(tablica1[i]);
    }

    Console.Read();

    int[] tablica2 = new int[20];

    for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
    {
      tablica2[i]=tablica1[20-i];
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@Sinatr Thank You for this topic. It was really helpful but there is only one table. 
@Filip Milovanović Yes, I have to make two two tables :) After reserving first, I should put elements from first to second. I changed this for, but in console I am still able to see only first one. :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Randomy1
{
    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] tablica1 = new int[20];

        Random tab = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            tablica1[i] = tab.Next(20);
            Console.WriteLine(tablica1[i]);
        }



        int[] tablica2 = new int[20];

       for (int j = tablica2.Length; j > 1 ; j--)
        {
            tablica2[j] = tablica1[20-j];
            Console.WriteLine(tablica2[j]);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    tablica2[i] = tablica1[20 - (i + 1)];

    Console.WriteLine("Tablica 1st :: " + tablica1[i] + " Tablica 1 Reverse "      + tablica1[20 - (i + 1)] + " Tablica 2 " + tablica2[i]);
}
```